# How to convert json array to list of strings using javax validation annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I am using the Javax. I have the pojo class as below:

```
Class A{

@JsonProperty("values")
    private List<String> values;

}
```

I am passing the data using the API like:

```
"values":["a","b"]
```

but in my java code I am not getting the values as list of strings.
I get the single value as `"[\"a\",\"b\"]"` instead.

I know using the converter I can conver it but is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Can you give more context of how you parse "values":["a","b"] String to your POJO?

Answer (score 0):

How do you parse `"values":["a","b"]` String to your POJO? If you parse correctly，you can get values as List.

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    String list = "{\"values\":[\"a\",\"b\"]}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        A a = objectMapper.readValue(list, A.class);
        //you can get values from a as list
        List<String> values = a.getValues();
        System.out.println(values);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Data
static class A implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private List<String> values;
}
```